# Close Angular md-dialog from an iframe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, mddialog

I am looking to see if it's possible to close a md-dialog (Angular Material) from an iframe, that iframe contains an other Angular App. The iframe is loaded into the md-dialog that I would like to close.

See an example:

```
<md-dialog class="modal-dialog contract-detail">
    <md-dialog-content flex="auto">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" ng-click="closeDialog()">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
      <iframe ng-src="{{urlIframe}}"
              frameborder="0"
              allowfullscreen
              style="position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;width: 100%;height: 90%;"
              align="center">
      </iframe>
    </div>
  </md-dialog-content>
</md-dialog>
```

The var {{urlIframe}} contains the Angular app URL.

Comment: Is `urlIframe` aware that it is in an iframe? Can you somehow provide a callback to the iframe? Also, you seem to be missing some closing tags in your code.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it seems when I was creating the post there was an error with the "code" button. It's fixed now. I need a callback from the iframe url app. Or I need in someway close the md-dialog on the app loaded into the iframe. I have tried `window.parent.close()`, but it doesn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access parent angular application's scope like,

```
var $scope = parent.angular.element('.modal-dialog.contract-detail').scope();
```

And then just calling the `closeDialog` function on `$scope`, would close the dialog.